# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSIndexSet'..?

Tags: swift2

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showView"
        {
            var upcoming: NewViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? NewViewController)!
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let titleString = self.objects.objectsAtIndexes(indexPath.row) as? String 

            upcoming.titleString = titleString
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
         }
    }
```

I am getting the following error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSIndexSet'..

in the line where I am trying to convert the value into string:

```
let titleString = self.objects.objectsAtIndexes(indexPath.row) as? String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let titleString = self.objects.objectsAtIndexes(indexPath.row) as? String`

You are asking for **objects** at **indexes** , but what you really want is **object** at **index**

you could just use `self.objects[indexPath.row]`